# Remove letter from cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I have list of UK postcodes. I want to find area and district value of postcode.

e.g. EN11 8HD  from this address i want to find "EN" and "EN11'. I got the district value with the help of "text to column(by Space). but how to get area code from the postcode?

```
G12 8QH
SW1W 0NY
GU16 7HF
L1 8JQ
```

Comment: Postcode rules are found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Validation It will be cumbersome to parse these with Excel while quite trivial in VBA. Do you prefer a Macro Solution (user defined function) or an array formula or many formulas in many columns?

Answer (score 0):

Need more explanation what actually want to do. Try below...

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EN",A1)),LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)-1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I have list of UK post code from which I want to find the area of the post code which (charcter value of 1st group of post code.

Comment: Please few sample data and your expected output for better understanding.